# How do I save API data into a csv file? Also how do I fix a traceback error?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, data-science

This is part of my code. It successfully makes an API call and receives the data from the API endpoint. I am trying to save this JSON data into a csv file, but I am not sure how. Also the API data is printed as unicode instead of a string - how do I fix that?

I have tried these lines of code:

Trial 1:

```
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(response, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Trial 2:

```
data = response.text
file_csv = open("File.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file_csv, delimiter = ' ')

for rows in basketball_data.split('\n'):
    writer.writerow(rows)
```

Trial 3:

I tried using Pandas, but that didn't work as well. Any recommendations?

**The code below is for fetching the API data which works.**

```
basketball_data = " "
URL = "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7"   #API 
# endpoint

# Dictionary to map HTTP authenticator and API key

Headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'd22e84f5c1fa4f4ab47bf1419bd94221', 'accept': 
"application/json", 'accept': "text/csv"}  

response = requests.get(url = URL , headers = Headers)  #get request parameters to 
print(response.status_code)  #Status code tells us if API call is successful
print(response.json())       #JSON object is returned
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()); df.to_csv(file, index=False)`, you can convert the json to dataframe first.

Comment: _"How do I save API data into a csv file?"_ _"I am trying to save this data into a json file"_ Which one is it?

Comment: Whoops I meant I want to save JSON data into a csv file.

Comment: @Ferris So the code before the ; would insert the JSON data into a Data frame. And the code after the semicolon would the read the data from the data frame into a csv file. Is that correct? Also, how would I define the file variable - I get this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment

Comment: any reason it needs to be CSV?  I'd recommend *pickle* as format for storage on disk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7"

headers = {
    "Ocp-ApimKey": ";wld4221",
    "accept": "application/json",
}

data = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("basketball_data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. I ran into a runtime error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128). Unfortunately, the response return by the API contains unicode, how do I remove the unicode?

Comment: You don't *remove* unicode. You *decode* it. Are you sure you're accessing the same url as in the question? I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerSeasonStats/2021.  (This is the updated link I am using)

Comment: Also, the data type of data is a list. Does this make decoding any differents?

Comment: Still, updating the link doesn't change much in my case. The code works and I'm able to get the data in the .csv format. No errors whatsoever. And no, the list doesn't have anything to do with decoding.

Comment: I get the same error, but it is only for a specific position. The data has been successfully loaded into a csv file. However, it isn't neat and organized like the data in your screenshot.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Look, if you're using the code I've provided you really should be getting any different results. If you do, however, update your question with error traceback and a screenshot of that disorganized .csv file.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8VeaaDa - Here is the link with the screenshot of my output. Let me know if you need any other material.

Comment: Uhm... what do you use to *open* the csv file? How about opening it with Excel or OpenOffice?

Comment: Oh I was using VIM, and using excel to open it slipped my mind. I can now see all my data in an organized manner. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: So, this code partially works. It successfully reads the data to a csv file, but it crashes after this function is over because of the unicode error. Due to this problem, I can't run the remainder of my python script. Any advice?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solutions given by the pandas documentation:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

basketball_data = " "
URL = "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7"   #API
Headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'd22e84f5c1fa4f4ab47bf1419bd94221', 'accept': 
"application/json", 'accept': "text/csv"}

response = requests.get(url = URL , headers = Headers)  #get request parameters to
print(response.status_code)  #Status code tells us if API call is successful
print(response.json())      #JSON object is returned

df = pd.json_normalize(response.json())
df.to_csv("data1.csv")
```